# How to create Angular Material Chips unique to each expansion panel?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

My goal is to create Angular Material Chips that are unique to each expansion panel. For example, panel 1 should have chips called chip 1 and chip 2, while panel 2 should have chip 3 and chip 4. However, the panels should all show up on a singular page (such as localhost:4200).

When I run my current code, it produces chips that appear on every panel, and when a chip is deleted, it is deleted from every panel as well. I believe that the solution lies in creating an *ngFor loop with tags being replaced with p.tags, where adding a tag will be unique to that object’s tags array. However, I can’t figure out how push that data back into a singular object and then display that data on my html page.

Here's what the .ts code looks like.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MatChipInputEvent } from "@angular/material/chips";
import { COMMA, ENTER } from "@angular/cdk/keycodes";

export interface People {
  people: Person[];
}

export interface Person {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  tags: string[];
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
})
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {

  persons;

  visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  addOnBlur = true;
  readonly separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];
  tags: string[] = [];

  constructor(private personService: PersonService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.personService
      .getStudents()
      .subscribe((data) => (this.persons = data.persons));
  }

  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    if ((value || "").trim()) {
      this.tags.push(value.trim());
    }

    if (input) {
      input.value = "";
    }
  }

  remove(tag: string): void {
    const index = this.tags.indexOf(tag);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.tags.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what the .html code looks like.

```
<mat-expansion-panel  *ngFor="let p of persons>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header [collapsedHeight]="'125px'" [expandedHeight]="'125px'">
        {{ p.name }}
 </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-chip-list #chipList>

        <!-- tags should be switched to p.tags here I think -->

        <mat-chip *ngFor="let tag of tags" [selectable]="selectable"
                 [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(tag)">
                {{tag}}
          <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
        <input placeholder="Add a tag"
               [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
               [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
               [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
               (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
      </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-form-field>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: if each person has a set of different tags you have to find a way to connect each person to their respective tags and if two persons share the same tag then those tags cannot be in coming from the save place because then if you remove tag1 on person one, tag1 will be removed from person 2 as well

Comment: I think the best thing is to have each person object have its own tags key which contains an array of tags for that person